# bit.dev with tailwind 3.0 and JIT

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss, bit.dev

I made tailwind 2.0 work with bit.dev however to use tailwind classes we have to define them in tailwind.config.js. Is there a workaround where purge is working as it should, or is there a way to make bit.dev work with tailwind 3 and the JIT compiler

I used this to set up tailwind 2 in bit.dev: https://github.com/teambit/react-tailwind-env

Comment: Have you already seen this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372457/how-to-use-bit-dev-with-tailwindcss ? Or this tutorial: https://dev.to/debs_obrien/adding-tailwindcss-to-bit-3mgb ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.